# 22.10 Battery does not charge if laptop shut - but not suspended

Tags: battery, 22.10

I have a Dell Inspiron 13-7359.  I have it set to remain on when the lid is shut (as it acts as my media server).  I have it set on Balanced mode.

It is **NOT** suspended.

I can see that the battery is gradually draining.

If I open the lid, it immediately starts charging right up to 100%.

Any ideas or do I just open the lid when I need it to charge?